# Шорткод "[product_category category="kategoriya-1"]" выводит только часть товаров категории

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Шорткод "[product_category category="kategoriya-1"]" выводит только часть товаров категории.

Я думал что он добавит внизу страницы кнопки для перехода на следующие страницы с товарами этой же категории, которые не уместились на этой, но этого не произошло и он вывел только 12 товаров из 60+.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В последних версиях WooCommerce поддерживает пагинацию в своих шорткодах. Добавьте в качестве аргумента paginate="true":

```
[product_category paginate="true" category="kategoriya-1"]
```

Comment: Это рабочий шорт код. Но вы поставили тире вместо нижнего подчеркивания и поэтому шорт код из вашего примера не работал! `[product_category paginate="true" category="kategoriya-1"]`

Comment: @Gevorg спасибо, поправил